# Delayed Job debug on production logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm setting up background tasks with `Rails 5` and `DelayedJob` for simple email notifications.

Looking into my production logs and it's coming up with the following item:

```
[2016-08-05T20:22:15.094172 #10616] DEBUG -- : 
Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (1.0ms)  UPDATE "delayed_jobs"
SET locked_at = '2016-08-06 10:22:15.092656', locked_by = 'delayed_job 
host:jiably pid:10616' WHERE id IN (SELECT  "delayed_jobs"."id" FROM 
"delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2016-08-06 10:22:15.091986' AND 
(locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2016-08-06 06:22:15.092073') OR 
locked_by = 'delayed_job host:vps-server-name pid:10616') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE) RETURNING *
```

There is no jobs in the queue and when I test my app's email notification the job seems to be processed fine.

Is this normal? It seems to be repeating frequently and adding to the log file. I do have logrotate setup but unsure if it's a configuration I did or miss to cause this.

Thanks for shedding some light into this.

Answer (score 0):

You may be seeing Delayed::Job issue 477 [here](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/477).  EDIT: I understand that you stated this occurred in production.  The fix, or your configuration, would need modified to match that concern.

If so, the fix is there.  I implemented config/initializers/delayed_job_config.rb as here (note that I have staging implemented):

```
Delayed::Worker.max_attempts = 5
Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = !Rails.env.test?
Delayed::Worker.sleep_delay = 10
Delayed::Worker.default_priority = 100

# Prevent excessive logging every 5 seconds when Logger level < WARN
# https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/477
if %w(development staging).include? Rails.env
  module Delayed
    module Backend
      module ActiveRecord
        class Job
          class << self
            alias_method :reserve_original, :reserve
            def reserve(worker, max_run_time = Worker.max_run_time)
              previous_level = ::ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level
              ::ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = Logger::WARN if previous_level < Logger::WARN
              value = reserve_original(worker, max_run_time)
              ::ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = previous_level
              value
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Is this thread safe? From what I understand AcitveRecord::Base.logger is shared will all other instances of AR classes

Comment: @Ruslan It seems you are certainly correct, especially since it is mentioned in the referenced issue.  I should have stated that.  I don't have time to do a deep analysis right now.  What impact would you expect?

Comment: I haven't done any analysis myself. But I am assuming that if `AR` runs a query (outside of worker) when the switcheroo happens then it won't be logged. The timing would have to be quite exact

Comment: Nightmare fuel.